# 5 Validation with RegEx for Bulgarian phone numbers

Tags: regex, laravel, validation, phone-number

I want to check my phone field in my form in laravel 5 with this RegEx validation rule:

```
(\+359|0)\s?8(\d{2}\s\d{3}\d{3}|[789]\d{7})
```

I tried this:

```
'phone' => 'required|regex:(\+359|0)\s?8(\d{2}\s\d{3}\d{3}|[789]\d{7})'
```

But my form doesn't catch this validation. I think that something is missing in my RegEx.

Comment: `'phone' => 'required|regex:/^(\+359|0)\s?8(\d{2}\s\d{3}\d{3}|[789]\d{7})$/'`? You forgot the delimiters and the anchors. Does it work? No point in using `\d{3}\d{3}`, I guess you mean to  match 6 digits at a row? Use `\d{6}`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need delimiters (in my example, `/`) around your regex:

```
'phone' => 'required|regex:/^(\+359|0)\s?8(\d{2}\s\d{3}\d{3}|[789]\d{7})$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add

```
<?php 
 return ['phone'      => 'required|regex:/^\+?[^a-zA-Z]{5,}$/'];
?>
```

I think this is fairly enough. If there is no example what is the format, use can add phone number like:

> +359878XXX,
>   +359 878 XXX,
>   +359 87 8X XX, 
>   +(359) 878 XXX, 0878-XX-XX-XX.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Laravel-Phone](https://github.com/Propaganistas/Laravel-Phone) package for Validation, Formatting and more functionality.

In your case you can specify you country like this :

```
'phone' => 'required|phone:BG'
```

*BG = Bulgaria*